# How to create multiple threads without using sleep in C

Tags: c, pthreads, producer-consumer

I'm tasked with writing a producer/consumer program where there are multiple consumers with each consumer corresponding to its own shared data struct, while the producer has access to all the shared data structs. Anyway, the problem I'm running into is initializing each consumer thread with its own struct; this is accomplished via each thread getting its own, unique number. IE, Thread 0 gets number 0 passed in as an argument, thread 1 gets number 1, etc. However, I can only get each thread to get its unique number with a call to sleep.

```
struct SharedData {
    int         isopen;
    int     refcount;   // reference count:  number of threads using this object
    unsigned int    front;      // subscript of front of queue
    unsigned int    count;      // number of chars in queue
    unsigned int    bufsize;
    pthread_cond_t buffer_full;
    pthread_cond_t buffer_empty;
    pthread_mutex_t mtex;
    fifo_t* queue;
    sem_t       empty_count;

    sem_t       full_count;
    sem_t       use_queue;  // mutual exclusion
};

struct OverSharedData{
    struct SharedData ** rep;
    int rop;
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
//Other Code
struct OverSharedData* remp = (struct OverSharedData*)malloc(sizeof(struct   OverSharedData));
rennit(remp);
struct SharedData * d = *(remp->rep + 0);

//Other Code
for (z=0; z<consumerthreads; z++) {
    remp->rop = z;

    pthread_create((Consumer_Threads+z), 0, Consumer, remp);
    usleep(100);

}
```

remp->rop is the differing argument for each thread that contains its specific number. If I comment out the usleep like so

```
 for (z=0; z<consumerthreads; z++) {
    remp->rop = z;

    pthread_create((Consumer_Threads+z), 0, Consumer, remp);

 }
```

I get this: Entered Consumer: 2

Entered Consumer: 2

Entered Consumer: 2

When I want: 
Entered Consumer: 0
Entered Consumer: 1
Entered Consumer: 2

The consumer code is here:

```
 void* Consumer(void *arg){
     pthread_mutex_lock(&grill);
    struct OverSharedData * de = (struct OverSharedData *)arg;
    printf("Entered Consumer: %d\n", de->rop);

    int numb = de->rop;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&grill);
 //Rest of code not necessary
```

How do I initialize these threads without using a sleep call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your struct is global, it will get updated before Z threads are created. IE. The variable `remp->rop` will be incremented Z times before the first thread is even executing.

Comment: My struct is allocated on the heap, check the edited code above

Comment: From what I see all that is done is a pointer `*de` is declared, which is then set to point to the struct `remp` through a pointer `*arg`. I may be wrong, but to me it doesn't look like a new struct is made; it simply points to the already existing `remp`.

Comment: Let me see if I can try to explain it better:
You have a struct `remp` in which is a variable `rop`.
Each time you spawn a thread, you set `remp->rop` to be the number of the thread to be spawned. Then you pass `remp`, a pointer, to `Consumer`. Consumer then looks back into the struct that the argument points to to get its number. However, `remp->rop` is updated by the block creating the threads before the thread starts. Since you passed a pointer, the value is not copied to the thread, and so `remp->rop` will be the number that it is updated to by the time the thread starts executing.

Comment: I didn't include that bit of the code, but it does work perfectly when I include the usleep() call

Comment: The reason it works when you include the usleep call is because the thread can access the `remp->rop` variable while your spawner block is sleeping. Therefore the variable can't be incremented before your thread starts executing the code.

What I'd recommend is having a variable for each thread. Spawning threads is asynchronous; using only 1 variable will cause these sorts of issues.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to have been of help!